# STL accumulate() function

Tags: c++, stl

How can I count number of elements that satisfies lower_bound(42), upper_bound(137)
from this code??

```
accumulate(values.lower_bound(42), values.upper_bound(137), 0);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`accumulate` does not count, it *accumulates*. You can of course accumulate 1s instead of the elements but that’s rather backwards. The direct answer is [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance), which gives you the number of elements between two iterators (i.e. between the lower and upper bounds you’ve specified):

```
auto result = std::distance(values.lower_bound(42), values.upper_bound(137));
```

Comment: @quetzalcoatl For unsorted values, you cannot use `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`. In particular, OP seems to be using a `map` or `set` type, since the functions are used as member functions.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: calling `values.lower_bound(42)` in the question hints at some ordered container.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: true! I did not notice that they were used as methods. Or rather, I noticed, but didn't pay enough attention to it, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think the solution you are looking for is `std::count_if` from the `algorithm` header. If you have a container `cont`, you could use it like this:

```
bool is_in_range(int x){
   return 42 <= x && x >= 137;
}

std::count_if(cont.begin(), cont.end(), is_in_range);
```

Comment: It’s worth noting that this is quite a bit less efficient than my solution – O(n) instead of O(log n).

Comment: It depends on the actual data: count_if does not benefit from the data being sorted. Take a sorted vector with 1G elements and 42 and 137 are in the first 5% of the vector. Your solution will scan the entire array.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I see that your answer fits the question better than mine, but I fail to see how your solution is `O(log n)`. Take an iterator without a distance type, and look at the following list of values (in the order they are iterated over) `[42, 43, 43, …, 43, 137]`. How many iterator calls does your solution take? O(n). Of course, you saved yourself the comparison function call, that is a plus. If you have a difference type, your algorithm is even `O(1)`. What is `O(log n)` about it?

Comment: Barring the `distance` call, finding the elements is log n.

Comment: @niklasfi: you are right, there are two different counts here. If we agree on `N` being the number of elements and `B` being the number of elements within the bounds, then using `distance(lower, upper)` is `O(log N)` comparisons and `O(B)` iterations whilst your solution is `O(N)` comparisons and `O(N)` iterations.